# Git Clone timeout error in SAP HANA XS Advanced to SAP IDE

Tags: git, hana, hana-xs

I would like to clone project from github to my SAP IDE and I am getting error.

> Clone request failed Request failed: Gateway Timeout URI:
>   /che/project/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky/import/tinyworld-1?force=true

I add in `JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_OPTS`:

> JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_OPTS: [java_opts: "-Dhttps.proxyHost=domainXXX.de -D
>   https.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=host"]

Can anyone tell me if I made something wrong? What should I enter for http.nonProxyHosts?

This is the output of `xs logs di-core --recent`

> 04.05.17 10:47:21.000 [RTR] OUT 172.28.103.9 - - to gisu546:51016 "POST /profile/prefs HTTP/1.1" 200 sent 1374 in 53 by
>   008-e68cd177-6ddd-4848-b69b-3681de484f9e 04.05.17 10:47:21.000
>   [APP/1-3] ACC 172.28.138.239 - - [04/May/2017:10:47:21 +0200] "GET
>   /runnerWs/14/children/.testresults HTTP/1.1" 200 2 04.05.17
>   10:47:21.000 [APP/1-3] ACC 172.28.138.239 - - [04/May/2017:10:47:21
>   +0200] "POST /profile/prefs HTTP/1.1" 200 -04.05.17 10:47:30.000 [RTR] OUT 172.28.103.9 - - to gisu546:51016 "GET
>   /workspace/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky HTTP/1.1" 200 sent 1239 in 45 by
>   008-e68cd177-6ddd-4848-b69b-3681de484f9e 04.05.17 10:47:30.000 [RTR]
>   OUT 172.28.103.9 - - to gisu546:51016 "GET
>   /project/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky/tinyworld HTTP/1.1" 200 sent 707 in
>   124 by 008-e68cd177-6ddd-4848-b69b-3681de484f9e 04.05.17 10:47:30.000
>   [APP/1-3] ACC 172.28.103.9 - - [04/May/2017:10:47:30 +0200] "GET
>   /workspace/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky HTTP/1.1" 200 1239 04.05.17
>   10:47:30.000 [APP/1-3] ACC 172.28.138.239 - - [04/May/2017:10:47:30
>   +0200] "GET /project/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky/tinyworld HTTP/1.1" 200 -04.05.17 10:47:47.000 [RTR] OUT 172.28.103.9 - - to gisu546:51016 "GET /workspace/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky HTTP/1.1" 200 sent 1239 in
>   44 by 008-e68cd177-6ddd-4848-b69b-3681de484f9e 04.05.17 10:47:47.000
>   [RTR] OUT 172.28.103.9 - - to gisu546:51016 "GET
>   /project/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky/tinyworld HTTP/1.1" 200 sent 707 in
>   123 by 008-e68cd177-6ddd-4848-b69b-3681de484f9e 04.05.17 10:47:47.000
>   [APP/1-3] ACC 172.28.103.9 - - [04/May/2017:10:47:47 +0200] "GET
>   /workspace/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky HTTP/1.1" 200 1239 04.05.17
>   10:47:47.000 [APP/1-3] ACC 172.28.138.239 - - [04/May/2017:10:47:47
>   +0200] "GET /project/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky/tinyworld HTTP/1.1" 200 - 04.05.17 10:48:17.000 [RTR] OUT 172.28.103.9 - - to gisu546:51016 "POST /project/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky/import/tinyworld-1?force=true
>   HTTP/1.1" - sent - in - by 008-e68cd177-6ddd-4848-b69b-3681de484f9e
>   04.05.17 10:48:32.000 [APP/1-3] ACC 172.28.138.239 - - [04/May/2017:10:48:32 +0200] "POST
>   /project/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky/import/tinyworld-1?force=true
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I tried to clone project from our intern Git and then I got another error:

> Clone request failed
>
> https://g431017@sgisbruap126.gisa-halle.de:8080/gitblit/r/gisa/sla/Freigabe-Test.git:
>   cannot open git-upload-pack

Do you have any solution to clone project from Git? Is there any command to investigate more the cloning process?

Answer (score 0):

Clone request failed Request failed: Gateway Timeout URI: /che/project/workspaceoiqcdmunycarr4ky/import/tinyworld-1?force=true

this errors comes when your di-core is not running.

check url `https://HOST_NAME:51037/` to see if di-core is really working or not.

and here `JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_OPTS: [java_opts: "-Dhttps.proxyHost=domainXXX.de -D https.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=host"]` I hope in place of "host" you are using actual host name right? If not use the actual host name and then try github clone again.